# Mock a thrown exception

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Is there a way to mock what a thrown exception in the try catch block? I want to test my function that the url string in `error.message` is indeed replaced with `replacedURL` string. How can I easily test it or mock the thrown exception to an object with this URL.

```
async function getUsers() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/api/users');

    if (response.status >= 400) {
      console.error('Could not fetch users');
      return;
    }

    const users = response.json();
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    let message = error.message;
    if (message) {
      message = message.replace(/https:\/\/some.url.com /g, 'replacedURL');
      delete error.message;
    }

    console.error('error', error);
  }
}
```

Here's my test

```
test('url in error message is replaced', () => {
  expect(getUsers()).toThrow('replacedURL');
})
```

Comment: try `expect(() => getUsers()).toThrow` instead? https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror

Comment: have you tried returning invalid json?

Comment: Note that your current implementation _doesn't_ replace the message on the error object, it removes it entirely and creates a new, unused string with the replaced URL in. But you need to read up on testing async functions (they return _promises_, in this case rejected rather than resolved) and think about how to get it into a failing state (how are you controlling responses in your other tests?) to start with.

Comment: @Tschallacka if I did, how would I mock the caught error? If I didn't mock it, it would say something like "invalid JSON".

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, I could test that the console error equals something but my question still stands, how would I mock that error to be `{ message: 'https://some.url.com' }`?

Comment: Under what circumstances would that happen to start with? With `fetch`, I think the error message is always just `"Failed to fetch"`. How do you control your requests and responses in your tests generally - are you using something like nock or msw, mocking fetch, ...?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I use `node-fetch` as well as `mocked` from `ts-jest/utils`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to actually throw an error in your function for it to be caught by `toThrow`.

Also, I'd recommend that your test doesn't actually tries fetching from the API (unless you're sure that's what you want it to do). Instead, consider using a custom caller (which can extend fetch) which you can then mock the response for, like `const caller = jest.fn().mockRejectedValue({ message: 'https:://some.url.com' });`